# $match aggregate not working with date range in node

Tags: node.js, mongoose, aggregate

This is the query condition。visitedDate ：type of date

```js
const s = new Date('2017/3/1')

const e = new Date('2017/3/2')
const filter = [
    {
        $match: {
            dataSource: 0,
            visitedDate: {
                $gte: s,
                $lt: e
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $limit: 10
    }
]
```

I using the mongoose aggregate in node, return "[]".
code:

```js
model.aggregate(filter, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        return reject(err)
    }
    return resolve(data)
})
```

Why, what should i do?

Comment: Could you send all your aggregate please ;). You need to specify an _id to aggregate

Comment: Did you verified in mongo schema, is there any data which matched with your search criteria because I am able to get the data if matched my criteria.

Comment: yes, i  verifed, use find query condition，it has results

Comment: Solved, thank you very much. is a string type conversion problem